# Consistent estimator of $p$ of Bernoulli trial

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, parameter-estimation, law-of-large-numbers

> Show that $Y_n:=\frac{1}{n+2}\left(1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$ is a consistent estimator of the success probability $p$. Here the $X_i$ denote $iid$ random variables that obey a Bernoulli distribution.

---

**My approach:**

Let be $\epsilon$ arbitrary but $\epsilon>0$. Then we find a $\delta$ such that $\epsilon>\delta>0$ and
$$
P(|Y_n-p|>\epsilon)\leq P(|Y_n-p|>\delta)=P\left(\left|\frac{1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i-np-2p}{n+2}\right|>\delta\right)\leq P\left(\left|\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}-p\right|>\delta-\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$
Now, we choose $n$ such that at least $n>\frac{2}{\delta}$. By Weak Law of Large Numbers we know that for some arbitrary $c>0$ there exists a $n_0$ such that for all $n>\max\left\{n_0,\frac{2}{\delta}\right\}$ it follows
$$
P(|Y_n-p|>\epsilon)\leq P\left(\left|\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}-p\right|>\delta-\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq P\left(\left|\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}-p\right|>\frac{\delta}{2}\right)<c.
$$
Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(|Y_n-p|>\epsilon)=0$.

---

My tutor said that I can't show the consistency of the estimator this way but I didn't understand what exactly is wrong with this approach. Maybe someone can give me feedback.

Comment: How do "we find a $\delta$ such that..." ?

Comment: If $t_n$ is a sequence of consistent estimators of a parameter $t,$ and $\varphi_n$ is a uniformly convergent sequence to the identity, then $\varphi_n(t_n)$ is another consistent estimator of $t.$ I believe you only need to prove $\frac{1}{n} \sum x_n$ is a consistent estimator of $p.$

Comment: @kimchilover, e.g. $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$...

Comment: @WilliamM. no, the estimator is clearly stated in the question. I don't understand why would be a problem if we had another consistent estimator?

Comment: Obviously you did not understand my comment. The function $\varphi_n(t) = \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{n}{n+2} t$ converges uniformly to the identy on $[0, 1],$ thus the result I wrote shows it suffices to show that $t_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_1^n x_i$ is a consistent estimator of $p.$ And this is much easier using WLLN.

Comment: Also the SLLN suffices; then argue that a.s. convergence implies convergence in probability.

Comment: @WilliamM. I don't understand what a sequence of consistent estimators should be. I only know *a* consistent estimator. So yes I didn't understand your comment. However, I still don't see where my proof breaks regardless from being a bit longer...

Comment: What is a consistent estimator according to you?

Comment: @WilliamM. we have the same definition as wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator

Comment: I imagined you had a wrong idea. You cannot have convergence in probability unless you have a sequence. An estimator is simply a function of the sample. The standard setting then says that your sample size grows with $n,$ and for every $n$ you have an estimator $t_n;$ consistency of this sequence means that $t_n \to t$ in some stochastic sense as the sample size (i.e., $n$) tends to infinity and where $t$ is a quantity of interest, often called "parameters."